# Ruby on Rails, Fixture using time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, timezone, fixtures

In my fixtures for unit testing, I have something like this:

```
time: <%= Time.now %>
```

This will give me the time based on the machine's time zone. I want to get the time in UTC, I tried this:

```
time: <%= Date.tomorrow.in_time_zone('UTC') %>
```

It says, in_time_zone is undefined. How can I get the UTC date/time in the fixtures?

Thanks,

Comment: Try with `Time.now.utc.in_time_zone`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will show current time in UTC:-

```
Time.now.utc
```

Example:--

```
1.9.3-p385 :003 > Time.now.utc
=> 2014-04-25 19:29:03 UTC 
1.9.3-p385 :004 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving like this

```
<%= Time.now.utc.in_time_zone %>
```